Не могу перевести точно в месяцы из кастомного плагина WordPress в поля yoast SEO
Изначально написал с помощью плагинов ACF + Polylang и WP Table Builder, и более менее работало. Но заказчик посчитал, что нужно меньше плагинов, и лучше свой создать. В Table Builder можно экспортировать код таблиц (сделаны в виде афилиатов).
Написал плагин, имеющий структуру: файл плагина, папка includes. В ней admin-menu и shortcodes.
Ниже код из functions:
// Шорткод для виведення року
add_shortcode('Year', 'custom_year_shortcode');
function custom_year_shortcode() {
    return date('Y');
}

// Шорткод для виведення кастомного місяця
add_shortcode('Month', 'custom_month_shortcode');
function custom_month_shortcode() {
    // Отримуємо кастомні назви місяців із налаштувань
    $months = get_option('month_shortlang_months', []);
    $current_month = date('n'); // Номер поточного місяця (1-12)

    // Повертаємо кастомне значення або стандартне, якщо кастомного немає
    return !empty($months[$current_month]) ? esc_html($months[$current_month]) : date('F');
}

// Фільтр для заміни значень у Yoast SEO Title і Meta Description
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'custom_seo_title');
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc', 'custom_seo_metadesc');

function custom_seo_title($title) {
    $current_month = do_shortcode('[Month]');
    $current_year = do_shortcode('[Year]');
    
    // Замінюємо змінні на значення шорткодів
    $title = str_replace('%%currentmonth%%', $current_month, $title);
    $title = str_replace('%%currentyear%%', $current_year, $title);

    return $title;
}

function custom_seo_metadesc($metadesc) {
    $current_month = do_shortcode('[Month]');
    $current_year = do_shortcode('[Year]');
    
    // Замінюємо змінні на значення шорткодів
    $metadesc = str_replace('%%currentmonth%%', $current_month, $metadesc);
    $metadesc = str_replace('%%currentyear%%', $current_year, $metadesc);

    return $metadesc;
}

// Дозволяємо обробку шорткодів у Yoast SEO
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc', 'do_shortcode');

В плагине, по умолчанию напротив названия месяца, месяц на английском. Для проверки, написал "Decembro", потом "Декабрь" или "Грудень", меняется на нужный написанный в обычном тексте и заголовках. А вот в полях Yoast SEO title и meta description, остается December, что в предвадительном просмотре, что через DevTools. Буду рад помощи, желательно как можно быстрее, сроки могут подгорать. С радостью отвечу на сопутсвующие вопросы.

Позволю дать намёк: если заказчик такой умный, что считает плагины, то говоришь ему, что свой корявый велосипед будет стоить больших денег. И тогда проблема решается или быстро или очень быстро.

Вы занимаетесь каким-то извращением, это не правильный подход и вы нарушаете процесс стандартной генерации текста в зависимости от локализации. Есть стандартные словари переводов WP при помощи которых безопасно и правильно подставляеться нужный контент. Ваш код написанный GPT это ерись. Бросайте этого идиота, тут нету правильного решения.

Та он хотел еще чтобы кастомные таблицы были. Почитал, можно через дивы делать в гутенберге
